# Limit Points of A Square

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am given a set that states that:

$A = \{(x,y) \in\Bbb R^2: 0\le x < 1 \text { and } 0\le y < 1\}.$

I have deduced (correct me if I' wrong) that the set, when drawn out, is an open square excluding the point $(0,0),$ as it is a closed interval. Because the set is open, I believe that the limit points are every interior and boundary point in the set, but I am asked to describe all of the limit points that are not contained in $A.$ I am unsure how to proceed; does anyone know where to go from here?

Thanks.

Comment: The limit points that are not contained in $A$ is the set $\{(1,y) | 0 \leq y \leq 1\} \cup \{(x,1) | 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$, i.e. the top and right sides of the square.

Comment: $(1,y)$ , $0\le y \lt 1$; $(x,1)$, $0\le x \lt 1$, and $(1,1)$.Your thoughts?

Comment: @PeterSzilas I agree. The boundary points located on the open intervals make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A is neither open nor closed.
Though (0,0) is in A, it is not an interior point.
Though (1,1) is a limit point of A, it is not in A.
Show A' = [0,1]×[0,1].